Communication between Web Browser and ArcGIS Pro addin
My company has a AutoCAD Map 3D addin written in C# which is loaded when AutoCAD starts up. It has capabilities like linking a map object with actual SQL Database records. We had a legacy application written in Visual Basic 6 which used to communicate with the AutoCAD instance and send commands like link, unlink etc.
However we upgraded the legacy application to web based solution. I was able to achieve the legacy app behaviour by creating a self hosted WebAPI inside the AutoCAD addin that acts as a listener and I make calls from my Web based application from the web browser to the self hosted webapi running inside AutoCAD and then I perform the link, unlink operations inside AutoCAD and send the response back to the web browser.
Now my company wants to support ArcGIS pro along with AutoCAD. I tried creating a self hosted webpi inside the ArcGIS addin but I havent been able to get it running at all. I keep getting Microsoft.Aspnet.core dll's missing or some or the other dll missing. I have been struggling to achieve this functionality.
I have around 10 years of coding experience with C#, Asp.net, Blazor etc so I am sure I am not doing anything wrong with the code. I even tried using websockets, signalR to act as a listener but nothing has worked.
Is it even possible to achieve this functionality with ArcGIS pro? Any suggestion is welcome. I just need to create a PoC to say that yes we can support ArcGIS pro as well.

Please share the error message about I keep getting Microsoft.Aspnet.core dll's missing or some or the other dll missing. We need more details to investigate the issue. And please also share the web server(use IIS or Kestrel). Then we can give you some suggestions.

@JasonPan Sorry I could not reply as I was traveling, However I was able to fix the issue by adding true in the csproj file. Thanks
